# Prolog program that i just dont get

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I have a a database of gender:

ex:

```
woman(jhon).
man(Pat)
man(leo), etc.
```

I need to write a function for a tennis match (Mixed doubles: so 2 different gender on each side). so if you request lets say:

`matchMixte(equipe(X,emma),equipe(Y,Z)) , X, Y, Z` should return combination of possible partners.

Sorry for the french.

- equipe means team.
- homme means man
- femme woman

I already have lots of thing but I know I'm on the wrong track. If you can't help me because of the length I'll understand

Here is my work so far.

```
matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)):-
femme(X),homme(Y),
femme(X1),homme(Y1),
 not(X=Y),not(X=Y1),not(X1=Y1),not(X=X1),not(Y=X1),not(Y1=Y).
matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)):-
femme(X),homme(Y),
femme(Y1),homme(X1),
 not(X=Y),not(X=Y1),not(X1=Y1),not(X=X1),not(Y=X1),not(Y1=Y).

matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)):-
femme(X1),homme(Y1);
femme(X),homme(Y),
 not(X=Y),not(X=Y1),not(X1=Y1),not(X=X1),not(Y=X1),not(Y1=Y).
matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)):-
femme(X1),homme(Y1);
femme(Y),homme(X),

 not(X=Y),not(X=Y1),not(X1=Y1),not(X=X1),not(Y=X1),not(Y1=Y).
```

Comment: You don't need four `matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1))` predicates - one will give you all the combinations.

Comment: so true, i complicated my life. CS drives me crazy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem you have is as your first predicate worked fine.

I would shorten it to this, though, as you don't need all of those `not` predicates:

```
matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)):-
    femme(X),homme(Y),
    femme(X1),homme(Y1),
    not(X=X1),not(Y=Y1).
```

I queried like this:

```
?- matchMixte(equipe(X,Y),equipe(X1,Y1)),
    write(equipe(X,Y)),
    write(equipe(X1,Y1)),
    nl,
    fail.
```

Comment: your solution is almost perfect, but when i assign a value to X1 i get false as result, the other variables work perfectly

Comment: @ApexPredator - You need to post all of your fact predicates in your question.